# Whether $f(x)= x^3 \sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$, $x\neq 0$ and $0$ if $x=0$ is differentiable everywhere.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I think that this function is not differentiable at points where $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}=n\pi$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. But I don't know whether it is correct or not.

Of course, the function is differentiable at $x=0$.
$\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \lim_{x\to 0+} x^{2}\sin \frac{1}{x} =0 $
Similarly,  $\lim_{x\to 0-} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=0.$

How to discuss the differentiability of this function at other points.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This function is everywhere differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the Quotient $$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=h^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{|h|}}\right)$$ and this tends to Zero for $h$ tends to Zero, since
$$\left|h^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{h}}\right)\right|\le h^2 \to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

For $x \neq0$, the map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\vert x \vert}}$ is differentiable. Hence $f$ which is the product of functions which are differentiable is differentiable at those points.

And you correctly proved that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. Hence $f$ is differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For $x = 0$ you have correctly proved differentiability.

For $|x| > 0$ note that $\tfrac{1}{|x|^{1/2}}$, $\sin(x)$ and $x^3$ are continuous and differentiable. As the given function can be written as *combination* (multiplication, composition ) of differentiable functions,  so it *is differentiable for $|x| > 0$*.

So the given function is differentiable everywhere.